# SQL select with dynamic count of "BETWEEN" conditions based on joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, hql, between

I want to add a messenger to my pet project, but I am having difficulty writing database queries. I use MySQL for this service with Hibernate as ORM. Almost all queries was written in HQL, but in principle I can use native queries.

Messenger can contain group conversations. In addition to writing messages, user can enter the conversation, leave it, clear personal message history. User sees all messages when he has been in a conversation, but he can also clear the history and see only messages after the last clearing.

Below I described the simplified structure of two tables important for this task.

Message table:

| ID | text | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first_msg | 1609459200 |
| 2 | second_msg | 1609545600 |

Member_event table:

| id | user_id | type | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1609459100 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 1609459300 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 1609459400 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1609545500 |

```
where type:
1 - user entered the chat,
2 - user leaved the chat,
3 - user cleared his own history of messages in the chat
```

**Is it possible to read all chat messages available to the user with one request?**

I have no idea how to check conditions dynamically: WHERE message's timestamps are between all "entered-leaved" cycles and after the last "entered" if not leaved BUT only after the last history clearing. If exists.

Comment: Which is your version of MySQL?

Comment: @trincot version of MySQL is 8.0.20

Comment: When exactly is entered-leaved is read? If the last event is 2? As in if the 4th row didn't exist in the member_event? Then history clear doesn't matter?

Comment: How is what you want different than read all messages at & later than last event, unless the event type is 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could proceed with these steps:

1. take the union of both tables and consider the records in order of time stamp
2. Use window functions to determine whether the most recent 1 or 2 type was a 1. We can use a running sum where type 1 adds one and type 2 subtracts one (and 3 does nothing to it). With another window function you could determine whether there is still a type 3 following. The combination of these two informations can be translated to a 1 when the line belongs to an interval that must be collected, and a 0 when not.
3. Filter the previous result to just get the message records, and only those where the calculation was 1.

Here is the query:

```
with unified as (
    select   id, text, timestamp, null as type
    from     message
    union
    select   id, null, timestamp, type 
    from     member_event
    where    user_id = 1),

validated as (
    select   unified.*,
             sum(case type when 1 then 1 when 2 then -1 else 0 end) 
                over (order by timestamp
                      rows unbounded preceding) * 
             min(case type when 3 then 0 else 1 end) 
                over (order by timestamp
                      rows between current row and unbounded following) valid
    from     unified
    order by timestamp)

select   id, text, timestamp
from     validated
where    type is null and valid = 1
order by timestamp
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you give some feed-back?

Comment: Hi @trincot! I'm too late, but yes, thanks to your answer and these window functions I reworked the chat service of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see, how you could match the Member_event table to the Message_table without an additional `FOREIGN_KEY`. Are you trying to assign the Messages available to the User via Timestamp?
If so try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MESSAGE_TABLE m
WHERE m.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
(SELECT TOP 1 TIMESTAMP FROM MEMBER_EVENT_TABLE WHERE type = 1 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) 
AND (SELECT TOP 1 TIMESTAMP FROM MEMBER_EVENT_TABLE WHERE type != 1 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC)
```

This at least should show the last Messages between join and clean/leave

Comment: There are many other fields like chat_id etc. I simplified tables for the question.

Comment: I did a minor error at the selects. Just patched it :D

Comment: The problem is that user can theoretically leave the chat, skip a certain number of messages, then rejoin the chat.

Comment: Its hard to check previously assigned messages via SQL. Might work with a WHILE loop, but I do not know how to properly do that :)

Comment: For the millionth time I am convinced that it does not matter how many programming languages and how well the developer knows if he does not know how to work normally with databases. This is about me, of course. :-)

Comment: The question appears to be related to MySQL